# How to loop using JSTL forEach to achieve custom structure?

Tags: java, html, for-loop, foreach, jstl

I've a model attribute(which is a List that contain names) in my JSP. e.g. `myList`

Now I can easily loop through the list in the JSP using forEach e.g.

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var = "singleItem" varStatus="status">  
  ${singleItem.name}
</c:forEach>
```

This works fine.
Now my requirement is that I've a structure where I need to show:

```
    <div id="top"></div>
      <p>name1</p>
      <p>name2</p>
    <div id="bottom"></div>

    <div id="top"></div>
      <p>name3</p>
      <p>name4</p>
    <div id="bottom"></div>

    <div id="top"></div>
      <p>name5</p>
      <p>name6</p>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
```

Here the name1, name2 etc. is in `myList`. So how do I run the forEach loop in such a way that I can achieve the above shown output.
I'm stuck. Please help me. :(

Comment: Check it out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884638/jstl-foreach-get-next-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Sotirios answer, which I personally upvoted, as well as the answer initially proposed by skaffman, is a really clever workaround of the initial problem, it may give rise to a NPE or require some checks done beforehand.

I would have definitely followed the alternative, or 'straight' way, in which all 'extra' markup tags (`<div>` tags in your case) should be inserted when necessary, like in:

```
<c:set var="length" value="${fn:length(myList)}"/>
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var = "singleItem" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${status.index % 2 == 0}">
        <div class="top"></div>
    </c:if>
    <p>${singleItem.name}</p>
    <c:if test="${(status.index % 2 == 1) or (status.index + 1 == length)}">
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Also note, that you should substitute ids of your `<div>` for style class to prevent duplicate ids in your JSP.

Comment: Awesome. This is an elegant solution. Thanks a lot, skuntsel. Thanks to @Sotirios too! Let me implement this on my code and then mark this as the answer. Thanks guys, it saved me a lot of time and headache!

Comment: You could as well notice that `length` variable is really redundant, and you can shorten the code further by changing `(status.index + 1 == length)` for a simple `(status.last)`. Initially I wanted to use the length of non-zero size as a `<c:if>` condition to include the whole `<c:forEach>` loop, but later discarded it, as it was redundant as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `varStatus` and `step` attributes to access two list indexes each time.

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="singleItem" varStatus="status" step="2">  
    <div id="top"></div>
        <p>${myList[status.index].name}</p>
        <p>${myList[status.index+1].name}</p>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</c:forEach>
```

Instead of using the `var`, you'll access the list by index. You obviously should check if you have an even number of elements, or you might get NPE.

Comment: Wow,This looks neat. Thanks for the solution.But the list can even have odd number of elements. How to fix that?