# Bootstrap collapse data-target with variable id

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have a list of lists of elements. I want to collapse each of these inner lists using a collapsible button from bootstrap. I've tried this:

```
<button id="button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" style="display : hidden">
   Click to collapse
</button>

<c:forEach items="${list.elements}" var="element">
   <div id="collapsibleElement" class="collapse in">
      ${element.content}
   </div>
</c:forEach>
```

This works if I have just one element in the list, after clicking the button the text collapses. However, it doesn't work for more elements in the list. A correct number of buttons is created, however after clicking any button only the text under first button collapses.

The id stays the same for all elements and my guess is that this may be cause of the problem. Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: yes, the problem is, I can't hardcode different ids, they need to be bound to the current iteration. Any idea how could I do that?

Comment: i don't know jsp syntax, but i'm sure you can use some kind of iterator in those for loop. Just append it to your id so you get collapsibleElement-0,collapsibleElement-1,collapsibleElement-2,collapsibleElement-n,collapsibleElement-n+1 as ids.

Comment: add varStatus to your forEach, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5885175/1415732